# Custom Form - Change SAVE button text depending on choice selection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, custom-list, custom-form, submit

I have a choice selection. Depending on the users selection I would like to change the text of the SAVE button on the custom form.

Example:
What would you like to do from this point?

- Apply for Support
- Submit Application

I would like the button to say APPLY on first Choice and SUBMIT on second choice.

Answer (score 1):

You simply user javascript or jquery for this. Trigger the change event on dropdown list. In this change event based on the selection value you simple change the Save button text.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the onchange event for your requirement

```
<html>
<head> 
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
     function changeColor() {
    // alert("Hai");
     var eID = document.getElementById("colors"); 
       var colorVal = eID.options[eID.selectedIndex].value; 
     var colortxt = eID.options[eID.selectedIndex].text;
    //alert("Hai"+colortxt);
     document.getElementById('btnSave').value=colortxt ;
    //document.getElementById('btnSave').text=colortxt ;
 } 
  </script>  

    </head> 
   <body>
  <select id="colors" onchange="changeColor()"> <option value="1">Red</option> <option value="2">Blue</option> <option value="3" >Green</option> <option value="4">Yellow</option> <option value="5">Orange</option> <option value="6" selected="selected">White</option> </select> <br><br> 
     <input type="button" id="btnSave"  text="Submit"  >
      </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks Tarlin. I will look at this and try it tomorrow. I will get back to you.

Comment: @garvon-77 have you tested the  script. Is it working..?

Comment: Cant get it to work in my SharePoint form.